# Will installing Macbuntu environment remove unity?

Tags: unity, macbuntu

I want to install Macbuntu in my Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) using [this tutorial](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/11/mbuntu-macbuntu-1410-transformation.html).

My question is : if I install Macbuntu environment, will I be able to use unity by logging out from Macbuntu and choosing unity environment or it will completely remove unity from ubuntu as the Gnome shell does?

Answer (score 1):

1st lines in your link:

> Mac OS (MBuntu) Transformation pack is ready for Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic/14.04 Trusty Tahr/Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca/17 Qiana (**Note: For best results use Unity/Gnome FallBack, and for previous Ubuntu versions link to posts are given)**
>
> This pack contains themes for GTK (supports: Unity, Gnome, Cinnamon, Mate, and Xfce),
>
> What's in this Version?
>
> ```
> Themes are shiny, smooth, fast, and looks like latest Mac
> Mac Boot Splash auto configuration
> Mac theme for LightDM-webkit auto configuration
> Separate GTK themes for each desktop (Unity, Gnome Classic, Linux Mint)
> Latest icon set
> Three docky themes
> Auto set themes and icons script
> ```

And it also has a very alternatives to Ubuntu software.

---

But the note states to use "unity" so I doubt it gets deleted. And what you are installing is not an OS; it is more a THEME pack with lots of extras.

Comment: I got my answer. I watched a video tutorial of noobslabs on youtube, macbuntu just makes changes in unity, it does not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking yourself this question, it is time to take a system backup and then try it out!  If you don't like the results, just restore your system backup and move on...

Oh? You don't have any system back-ups yet??? Well then head [over here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) and start reading the question: For the answer: You're user type 4.

Comment: I got my answer. I watched a video tutorial of noobslabs on youtube, macbuntu just makes changes in unity, it does not remove it.

Comment: Please!  Read the Q&A on [What's a good strategy on backing up 1 PC](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) If you upvote over there, I'll immediately come and delete this answer here and move yours more to the top...  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. I just watched a [video tutorial of installing Macbuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saBxi_RKoKs), it just makes changes in unity environment. MacBuntu will not be installed as another environment like xfce or lxde so it will not remove unity from Ubuntu.